# Shiny height of well panel doesn't adjust to content

Tags: html, r, twitter-bootstrap, layout, shiny

I'm using a conditional panel inside a well panel of my shiny app. Sadly the height of the well panel doesn't adjust to the conditional panel. My code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

supp_distr_names <- c("Normal", "Uniform")

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(fluidRow(
  wellPanel(
    selectInput("distribution",
                "Select distribution:",
                choices = supp_distr_names),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.distribution == 'Normal'",
      column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_mean", "Mean:", value = 0)),
      column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_var", "Variance:", value = 0))
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distribution == 'Uniform'",)
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to make the height of `wellPanel` adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by your strange `fluidRow(fluidRow(`. This works fine like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(
    selectInput("distribution",
                "Select distribution:",
                choices = supp_distr_names),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.distribution == 'Normal'",
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_mean", "Mean:", value = 0)),
        column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_var", "Variance:", value = 0))
      )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distribution == 'Uniform'",)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style = "padding: 80px;"` to the `wellPanel`

```
library(shiny)
supp_distr_names <- c("Normal", "Uniform")

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(fluidRow(
  wellPanel(
    selectInput("distribution",
                "Select distribution:",
                choices = supp_distr_names),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.distribution == 'Normal'",
      column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_mean", "Mean:", value = 0)),
      column(width = 6, numericInput("normal_var", "Variance:", value = 0))
    ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distribution == 'Uniform'",),
    style = "padding: 80px;"
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```