# How to stretch wellpanel vertically in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a layout for 3 wellPanel side by side. The input elements available for each panel are different. However since first one doesn't have many inputs, it looks short and weird compared to others
[image: Screenshotof wellpanels]

Is it possible to stretch the first wellpanel(containing A) vertically so it looks similar to other two? Here's the code to reproduce the scenario

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,wellPanel(fluidRow(
      column(12,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "a", label = "A", 
        value = 0, currencySymbol = "%", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        decimalPlaces = 2,digitGroupSeparator = ","))
    ))),
    column(4,wellPanel(fluidRow(
      column(12,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "b", label = "B", 
        value = 0, currencySymbol = "%", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        decimalPlaces = 2,digitGroupSeparator = ",")),
      column(6,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "X",
        label = "X", value = 0, 
        currencySymbol = " %", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        digitGroupSeparator = ",",decimalPlaces = 2)),
      column(6,radioGroupButtons(inputId = 'X1',
                                 label = 'X1',
                                 choices = c('No','Yes'),justified = TRUE,
                                 direction = 'horizontal'))))),
    column(4,wellPanel(fluidRow(
      column(6,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "c", label = "C",
        value = 0, currencySymbol = "%", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        decimalPlaces = 2,digitGroupSeparator = ",")),
      column(6,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "L", label = "L",  
        value = 0, currencySymbol = "%", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        decimalPlaces = 2,digitGroupSeparator = ",")),
      column(6,autonumericInput(
        inputId = "Y",
        label = "Y", value = 0,
        currencySymbol = " %", currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
        digitGroupSeparator = ",",decimalPlaces = 2)),
      column(6,radioGroupButtons(inputId = 'Y1',
                                 label = 'Y1',
                                 choices = c('No','Yes'),justified = TRUE,
                                 direction = 'horizontal'))
    )))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does this question help: [Shiny height of well panel doesn't adjust to content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63380544/8366499)

Comment: thanks for the link~ unfortunately it does not